# Cloud function for firebase to redirect to a URL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a download endpoint for my mobile app. The app is available on app store and play store. I want to have a single URL that can be used by users to download the app on either an iOS device or an Android device. I was trying to find out if I can create a cloud function for firebase for this purpose. I was thinking of checking the `user-agent` for the request and based on whether the request came from an iOS device or an Android device or a web browser, redirect the user to an appropriate URL. I have verified that the device information is present in the `user-agent` header. For e.g.

```
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14C89 Safari/602.1 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: s~gcf-http-proxy)"
```

I guess the next things to do was to redirect the user to the app store URL in the above case. I tried to use `res.redirect` but that doesn't work. That ends up redirecting the user to `cloud-function-base-url/redirect-url` instead of just `redirect-url`.

Below is the code for the cloud function which is just trying to redirect to www.google.com when the function is triggered from the browser.

```
exports.appDownload = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log(stringify(req.headers))
  // This will eventually redirect to a store URL based on the phone in user-agent
  res.redirect('www.google.com');
});
```

This ends up redirecting the browser to `base-url/www.google.com` instead of just `www.google.com` and I get an error message saying `Not Found`. I wanted to redirect the browser to just `www.google.com`.

I wanted to check if it is possible to achieve the above using a cloud function for firebase.

Comment: Please show your code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to check if it is possible to redirect the browser to a different URL (the app store url in my case) if I invoke a cloud function from a browser. I have posted the code that I tried.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [documentation for redirect()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) suggests that you have to give it a fully qualified URL.  Note the scheme "https" is present here (you're just giving "www.google.com", which would be taken as a path relative to the current URL):

```
res.redirect('https://www.google.com/')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer. It works. Go Firebase!

Answer (score 4):

Recently the Firebase Team released the "Dynamic Links" feature, that does exactly what you want, and more.

[Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/)

Comment: This is deprecated.