# Firebase cloud storage static url for updating file

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I use a cronjob to call an http cloud function every day that updates a sitemap.xml inside cloud storage with dynamic data. Every time this file is updated, the token at the end of the url changes, making the old url unavailable to Google Search Console.

Is there a way to get a static url for a file that's repeatedly updated file in cloud storage?

Comment: Can you grab the URL using a firebase cloud function that simply redirects to the new URL?  [cloud function url redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890908/cloud-function-for-firebase-to-redirect-to-a-url)

Comment: There are no permalinks in Cloud Storage to files that are continually updated.  You'll need to construct a solution on your own, which depends on how your clients work.

Comment: I guess I can build another function that checks for the current url through the admin sdk on redirect as James suggests... I just wanted to know if there was a simpler way to get a permalink before doing that. Thanks anyways!